# Check if list has a list of values

Tags: algorithms, search, list

I have been trying to figure out an efficient algorithm that can check if a list of values contains a list of values. Both lists are sorted in ascending order.

For example:

Check if

`var listToSearch = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

contains

`var searchValues = [1,2,3]`

Without iterating through the list for each value in `searchValues`. Nor do I want to use something like binary search for each value in `searchValues`.

I tried creating a modified binary search for this but it does not work.
Is there some modification of binary search but for multiple search values or any other algorithm designed for this problem?

Edit: I want to check if `listToSearch` has ANY of the values in `searchValues` (not the entire sublist). So, for example the algorithm could return [true, true, true] since 1,2, and 3 are all found in `listToSearch`

Comment: If the list you are searching doesn't have duplicates or you don't care about duplicates, you could use hashing to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: The lists wont have duplicates. Could you explain a little better? Thanks :)

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/280361/list-comparing-techniques-for-faster-performance

Comment: What do you mean the binary search does not work ? Let j be the leftmost index where you start the binary search (initially 0). You binary search for the first element and if you find it you update j and then binary search for the second element starting at index j + 1 and so on.

Comment: Could you clarify whether "contains a list of values" means that the list must contain all of the search values or that the list must contain a sublist that matches the search values?

Comment: If both lists are sorted, and you're just checking if the shorter list is a "subrange" of the longer list, this seems like an extremely trivial problem as you can look for the shorter list's first element in the longer list (with binary search) then check the elements after it until you know if they all match or not. Could you describe in more detail what you tried and why it didn't work, or why what I just said doesn't apply?

Comment: @Adrian a custom modified binary search I made does not work. Binary search is only used to search for one value at a time.

Comment: @Blrfl Look at edit :)

Comment: Also, even though Adrian's solution is better than just doing binary search every time on the whole list there is the issue where most of the search values are not in the list to search. Then I would end up binary searching the entire list multiple times even though I already obtained information from comparisons and could prevent this.

Comment: I don't think you can prevent this. Sure, you do gather some information from previous binary searches, but how do you use it efficiently ? I think binary search is as good as it gets here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a linked list, then you are going to need to iterate each elements in sequence. You can have a binary search if you use an array instead.

Let's call L the list you are searching, and V the list of values that are searched for.

Your search function should return the sublist of L that follows the element *v* from V that you are searching for. Since elements are sorted, you know that the next element in V is going to be greater than *v*, and thus you only need to search in the sublist that follows *v* in L.

For example, say your lists are named as follow:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
V = [3,4,7,8]
```

1. Search for 3 in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].
2. Search for 4 in [4,5,6,7]
3. Search for 7 in [5,6,7]
4. Search for 8 in []

Anytime your search returns an empty list, the result for the search element is false (true otherwise). Since you advance in both lists at the same time, you are avoiding some useless search.

Answer (score 0):

Since both lists are sorted, you can do this with a slightly modified merge algorithm. You don't say what language you're using for, so I'll use a C-like psuedocode:

```
// ListToFind is the list of items to look for
// ListOfItems is the list of items to be searched
ixListToFind = 0   
isListOfItems = 0

while (ixListToFind < ListToFind.Count && ixListOfItems < ListOfItems.Count)
{
    if (ListToFind[ixListToFind] < ListOfItems[ixListOfItems])
    {
        // This item not found in the list. So move to the next one.
        ixListToFind = ixListToFind + 1
    }
    else if (ListToFind[ixListToFind] > ListOfItems[ixListOfItems])
    {
        // Move to the next item
        ixListOfItems = ixListOfItems + 1
    }
    else
    {
        // Found the item
        // Output or process it ... whatever.
        // Then move to the next item
        ixListToFind = ixListToFind + 1
    }
}
```

This works well if the number of items to find and the size of the list you're searching in are relatively similar in size. If you're looking for 5 items in a list of 20, for example, this will be great. But if you're looking for 100 items in a list of a million, then you'll probably want to use binary search. It depends on how many times you'll look for items in the same list.